# After installing gnome desktop, desktop disappeared

Tags: unity, gnome, 13.10

I need your help in order to get out of a mess I've got in. After installing successfully Ubuntu 13.10, I wanted to install some missing codecs in order to open mp3 and mp4 files. I found the solution in a website page which as well was explaining how to change the desktop interface installing gnome desktop. I should have never done it. I have neither experience nor skills in dealing with operative systems.
I entered this command line:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

consequently, the background changed to black (dark grey) and icons disappeared.
I have no clues about how to get rid of this gnome and restore Unity which served me so well in at least three happy years of using Ubuntu without issues.
Sorry for my broken English.

I hope you could help me, and I beg you not to scold me too much for my imprudence.
Thanks a lot
Alberto Costa

Answer (score 1):

- Login into virtual console and then run the below commands to remove gnome-shell and reinstall unity,

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop

  sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  ```
- Then restart lightdm,

  ```
  sudo service lightdm restart
  ```

Comment: the command sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop returns gnome-shell and gnome-desktop not installed... maybe I succeeded in uninstalling that... the worst thing is that lightdm restart shuts down all the environment (lets me with a series of logs I can't understand) and obliges me to turn off the computer in order to make it work

Comment: did you reinstall unity and ubuntu-desktop?

Comment: however, when I turn on the computer, when starting ubuntu (with the second to last kernel, because the last doesn't work) I see the gnome logo instead of the ubuntu one

Comment: It appears I'm using unity but the desktop is missing..

Comment: did you login into virtual console and then run the above codes?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Comment: yes I did it, it returns to me thet gnome shell and gnome desktop are not installed. lightdm restart shuts down the environment and it's impossible to get back without turning off the computer

Comment: i saw the topic but for my luck dash and launcher work, nautilus works as well. only desktop is grey, no icons. I can use all the apps as well.

Comment: I tried to restart unity. with the command line: