# How to get gnome shell 3.12 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I know there is a distro for ubuntu dedicated to gnome and I know ubuntu 14.04 comes with gnome 3.10. But I am wondering what the steps are to:

- Install the ppas for gnome 3.12
- install gnome 3.12
- only use gnome 3.12 (with no option for unity)

**Note:** Other answers in the similar category show getting the supported version by ubuntu, the "already packaged version" how ever there are steps to get 3.12, which doesnt come with ubuntu 14.04 and requires PPA installation.

Those steps are the steps I am looking for, not "open the software centre and download gnome" because that 3.10

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome)

Comment: @Jobin actually while it might be, ubuntu 14.04 DOESNT come with 3.12, it comes with 3.10 and I want the instructions to get 3.12

Comment: @Jobin Updated OP

Comment: Did you have a look at this answer in the above question: http://askubuntu.com/a/117026/72576? It is for 12.04 but should work for 14.04 too.

Comment: @Jobin yes, again that answer will help me install gnome shell 3.10 on ubuntu 14.04 I want 3.12 - ubuntu 14.04 doesn't come with 3.12, it ships with 3.10

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot update to GNOME 3.12](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452176/cannot-update-to-gnome-3-12)

Comment: When I upgraded to Gnome 3.12 on 14.4, I was unable to lock the screen anymore. I ended up purging that ppa and reverting. Are you able to lock the screen via the CTRL + ALT + L ?

Comment: I followed the Steps answered by Wilf to install Gnome and now I have lost unity! How do I get back unity. ????? Tried lots of steps but in vain http://askubuntu.com/questions/462914/how-to-reinstall-unity-desktop-on-ubuntu-14-04 http://askubuntu.com/questions/413356/after-installing-gnome-desktop-desktop-disappeared Nothing worked. Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just need to install a couple of Gnome apps, add the gnome3-staging prepository and do a dist-upgrade:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-weather gnome-maps gnome-photos gnome-music
```

Via http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-gnome-3-12-on-ubuntu-gnome-14-04-trusty-tahr/

When I did this myself I got errors like these:

> Error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-session_3.12.1-0ubuntu1~trusty1_all.deb (--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/share/upstart/sessions/gnome-session.conf', which is also in package gnome-session-bin 3.9.90-0ubuntu12"
>
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-session_3.12.1-0ubuntu1~trusty1_all.deb
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

To fix that if you get the same, force the package to install (which will over-write the existing gnome-session.conf file) with:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-session_3.12.1-0ubuntu1~trusty1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: The add-apt-repository command probably needs to be run first.

Comment: i have followed the same steps as you said but it is not getting installed

Comment: If you don't have gnome-shell installed at all are there other steps that need to be taken?

Comment: @Dason Do you even have Ubuntu GNOME? If not, there's your first step: installing that.