# How can I safely upgrade from Gnome 3.10 to 3.12 WITHOUT getting 3.14?

Tags: gnome, upgrade

Every method I see is to use the Gnome staging PPA, but this will blow past 3.12 and give me 3.14, is there no other way? This is for a system I need to be as stable as possible so I don't want anything in development.

Comment: If by stable you mean you are using ubuntu 14.04 you should then stick with the gnome version released with it, 3.10.

Comment: @xangua - can't do that, thats boring *(but might break the system. :)* Anyway, gastronomin, have you tried [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452864/how-to-get-gnome-shell-3-12-on-ubuntu-14-04) - looking at the [Gnome staging PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging), you should get 3.12 still, and not 3.14 *(which is only available for utopic 14.10 currently in the PPA - which however this will be an issue when 14.10 [gets released](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseSchedule) so marking this as a dupe probably ain;t a good idea)*.

Answer (score 0):

in 14.04 the staging PPA is your best bet for 3.12.
If you are using 14.10, https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3 gives you complete gnome 3.12